# How to match a column against an array of seach strings?

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching

I have a table `jsondocs` with the following columns:

```
id SERIAL
json TEXT
```

I want to check if the columns `json` contains some values but not exact match.

For example I can to do something like:

```
select * from jsondocs where json like '%id:123%'
```

But for an array containing 100 values. I mean something like (pseudo-code):

```
select * from jsondocs where json like in ('%id:123%','%id:123234324423243%',...)
```

I want to do a "like" search from values provided in an array.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us a sample JSON value that you want to search

Comment: Well iot may be a json but also can be any value from a text field. The is more what I am more interested in.

Comment: It makes no sense to treat a JSON value like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 approaches in your problem:

## Approach 1

Search as text combining like and any:

```
select * from jsondocs where json like any(ARRAY['%id:123%','%id:123234324423243%',...])
```

## Approach 2

If you know that the json will have a specific key and the values belong to a specific key in the json field then use this approach:

Assuming that json column contains the following:

```
{
  "mykey":"somevalue"
}
```

```
select * from jsondocs where json::jsonb->>mykey like any(ARRAY['%id:123%','%id:123234324423243%',...])
```

Generally if you want to do a like from a values in an array use:

```
mycol like any(ARRAY[^values^])
```